# Angular Protactor test getting h1 text from html

Tags: html, angular, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

I am very new in end to end testing. In my app I have a login page, which I want to show the user when they logout from the app. Now there is a text h1 inside the div. But I am not getting the text from that div and that is why the expected result is different from the actual result.

Here is my login page html.

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="login-controller">


    <div layout="column" class="login-dialog">

        <h1>Here is a heading</h1>
        <h2>Second Heading</h2>
        <div class="border">

           ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my app.po.ts

```
    async getLogInPage(){
    return await element(by.css('h1')).getText();
    }

    async logoutOfApplication() {
    var userMenu = element(by.css(".prof-dropbtn > span"));
    browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(userMenu), 10000);
    await userMenu.click();

    var logoutButton = element(by.id("logout"));
    await logoutButton.click();
  }
```

Now app.e2e-spec.ts

```
    it('Test for logout', () => {
    page.logoutOfApplication();
    expect(page.getLogInPage()).toEqual('Here is a heading');
    page.loginToApplication("email.com", "demo");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want get h1 value you have to write like this

```
it('Test for logout', () => {
        page.logoutOfApplication();           
        expect(element.all(by.css('.login-dialog h1')).getText()).toEqual('Here is a heading');
        page.loginToApplication("eamil.com", "demo");
      });
```

Comment: it showsExpected [  ] to equal 'Tomorrow's Operation'.
Expected :"Tomorrow's Operation"
Actual   :[]

Comment: do you have multiple h1 element?

Comment: yes, in a project there are multiple but in the login html only 1

Comment: try to add   browser.sleep(3000);

Comment: A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\mnowshin\projects\beck-hb\hb-frontend\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:4470:23)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)

Comment: check this https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all